# Application of Law of Iterated Expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Could you please explain something from a text I am reading?

We're given that $E(\epsilon_i)=0$ and $E(\epsilon_i x_i)=0$ for $i\geq 1$. Write $g_i=\epsilon_i x_i$ and we further know that
$$
E(\epsilon_i|g_{i-1},g_{i-2},\ldots,g_1)=0.
$$
Then, the author claims that the Law of Iterated Expectations implies
$$
E(\epsilon_i|\epsilon_{i-1},\epsilon_{i-2},\ldots,\epsilon_1)=0.
$$
How does he deduce that?

I tried
$$
E(\epsilon_i|\epsilon_{i-1},\epsilon_{i-2},\ldots,\epsilon_1)=E[E(\epsilon_i|\epsilon_{i-1},\epsilon_{i-2},\ldots,\epsilon_1,x_{i-1},x_{i-2},\ldots,x_1)|\epsilon_{i-1},\epsilon_{i-2},\ldots,\epsilon_1]
$$
but this led nowhere.

**Edit**: we're also given that $\{\epsilon_i\}$ is strictly stationary and ergodic and $\{g_i\}$ is a Martingale difference sequence (i.e. $E(g_i|g_{i-1},g_{i-2},\ldots,g_1)=0$).

Comment: Did you understand the answer that you accepted (40 minutes after it was posted)?

Comment: What is your source for the assertion you are asking us to prove?

Comment: @Did: it's from Hayashi's Econometrics

Comment: @yurnero: I made a mistake in my answer (now deleted) below. Big thanks to Did for pointing it out.

Comment: As stated, the assertion is wrong (try $x_i=0$ for every $i$).